# How to calculate the combinations of people picking names out of a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to calculate the probability in this situation:

N people put their name in a hat and then each person takes out a name. what is the probability that exactly X people take out their names?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671499/probability-four-people-pick-their-own-names-out-of-a-hat) answer but it doesn't explain how to calculate the solution for other numbers.

I understand that this is really a question of combinatorics. for example if there were 5 people there are 120 combinations. I need to calculate how many of those exactly X people get their names.

Comment: Look at partial derangements.

Answer (score -2):

The sample space is exactly as you found. The total number of combinations is indeed 5!. Now for X people to choose their names, this would mean their order is fixed whilst the other N - X people can either choose their names ( or not). The total number ways of this happening is (N - X)! ( As the order does matter and is done without replacement). So, the probability that exactly X people choose their names is (N - X)! / N!

Comment: you need to guarantee that exactly $X$ people pick their name and no more.